# Why aren't self-types looked up when calling a method on a constrained trait?

Tags: scala, self-type

Assuming

```
trait A { def t : Int }
trait B { this: A => }
```

why is it that the compiler doesn't "know" that I can call `t` on `B`?

```
def test(b: B): Int = b.t // doesn't work
```

but that I (apparently redundantly?) need to do

```
def test(b: B with A): Int = b.t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-types are not part of the contract of a trait or class.  That is to say, they don't provide *externally* visible restrictions on a trait or class, only *internally* visible ones.   Self-types are checked at object instantiation time, but are otherwise only usable by the declaring trait or any inheriting traits/classes/objects.  In Java terms, you could think of a self-type as being something like a a `protected interface` declared by the trait (although Java of course doesn't actually support such a thing).

If you wanted your test to work, you would need to make the dependence of B on A externally visible.  This is done with an "extends" declaration, a.k.a. simple subclassing

```
trait A { def t : Int }
trait B extends A
def test( b: B ) : Int = b.t
```

Comment: Okay, got it. Well one can make the self-type visible at least:

    `trait B { this: A => def a = this }`

    `def test( b: B ) : Int = b.a.t`